# PHP Switch statement displaying case label in echo statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have used the following SWITCH statement to ECHO one of three CASE's. However when I do this the output to the web page shows the CASE label then the actual echo-ed statement.

`$sc_stk_poa` is a boolean field of either `0` or `-1`.
`$sc_stk_prc_stanard` is a price field in the MySQL database.

```
echo $x = $sc_stk_poa;
switch($x) {
    case 0: echo "£{$sc_stk_prc_standard}";
        break;
    case -1: echo "POA";
        break;
    default: echo "";
}
```

The output I get in the webpage is something like: `-1POA` or `0£59.14` depending which case is selected to output.

Comment: remove the "echo" at the start of your php-code: `<?php $x=$sc_stk_poa; SWITCH ($x) { case 0: echo "£{$sc_stk_prc_standard}"; break; case -1: echo "POA"; break; default: echo ""; } ?>`

Comment: It seems that you're echoing `$sc_stk_poa` before the switch statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write less convoluted things :

```
<?php 
switch ($sc_stk_poa)
{ 
    case 0: 
      echo "£{$sc_stk_prc_standard}"; 
    break; 
    case -1: 
      echo "POA"; 
    break; 
    default: 
      echo "";
}
```

There was no need for variable $x, was it?

Comment: Thank you everyone, each one of the solutions mentioned here worked correctly. I can see my error's more clearly now that they were pointed out. Your time is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not displaying the label. You have an echo here: `<?php echo $x=$sc_stk_poa;`. This is the one outputting the value of `x`, which is used in your cases.